# Use checkboxes to check which column that are to be deleted

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

I'm making a panel where you can add your API's.
Problem is now, I need to make the user able to delete certain columns and also update a column.

```
$use = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM api");
//Panel
echo '
<!---Buttons-->
<a href=\'?addnew\'>Add new</a> <a href=\'?update\'>Update</a> <a href=\'?delete\'>Delete all selected columns</a>
<!---Table-->
<form method=\'POST\' action=\'?\'>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<!---Main Columns-->
<td></td>
<td>ID:</td>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>URL:</td>
<td>Format:
</tr>';
while($us = $use->fetch_array()){
    //print all API's
    echo'
    <tr>
    <!---All values to be echoed, ID is the only one who can\'t be updated from the panel-->
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'.$us['id'].'"></td>
    <td>'.$us['id'].'</td>
    <td><input type=\'text\' name="name'.$us['id'].'" value=\''.$us['name'].'\'></td>
    <td><input type=\'text\'  name="url'.$us['id'].'" value=\''.$us['url'].'\'></td>
    <td><input type=\'text\'  name="format'.$us['id'].'" value=\''.$us['format'].'\'></td>
    </tr>';
}   
echo'</table></form>';
```

This is some of what I've made so far. That's for the panel itself basicly.

This is what I'm using to update and delete

```
if (isset($update)) {
    while($us = $use->fetch_array()){
        if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE api SET name='".$_POST['name'.$us['id']]."', url='".$_POST['url'.$us['id']]."', format='".$_POST['format'.$us['id']]."'") == TRUE) {
            echo 'Updated';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=api%20(2).php">';
        }

    }
}
if (isset($delete)) {
    while($us = $use->fetch_array()){
        if (isset($_POST['checkbox'.$us[id]])) {
            if ($mysqli->query("DELETE FROM api WHERE id = '".$us['id']."'") == TRUE) {
                echo 'Success';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=api%20(2).php">';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also thinking of implementing some ajax into this, so if you want to you could help me out with that aswell :)

Problem is it won't retrieve the POST for some reason, I have no clue why though. Would be great if one of you could either provide me a solution to my current code or find a better alternativ on doing this. Thanks

Comment: give id to checkbox value, and use that into loop

Comment: What? You mean I should add a value to the checkbox?
But how does that help really? It won't retrieve any posts, even with var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    <a href=\'?addnew\'>Add new</a> <a href=\'?update\'>Update</a> <a href=\'?delete\'>Delete all selected columns</a>
    <!---Table-->
    <form method=\'POST\' action=\'?\' id="">
```

with

```
    <a href=\'?addnew\'>Add new</a> <a href=\'javascript:void(0)\' onclick=\'document.getElementById("frm").value(\'update\');document.getElementById("frm").submit()\'>Update</a> <a href=\'javascript:void(0)\' onclick=\'document.getElementById("frm").value(\'delete\');document.getElementById("frm").submit()\'>Delete all selected columns</a>
    <!---Table-->
    <form method=\'POST\' action=\'?\' id="frm">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="">
```

replace

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox'.$us['id'].'"></td>
```

with

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="'.$us['id'].'"></td>
```

replace

```
    if (isset($update)) {
        while($us = $use->fetch_array()){
            if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE api SET name='".$_POST['name'.$us['id']]."', url='".$_POST['url'.$us['id']]."', format='".$_POST['format'.$us['id']]."'") == TRUE) {
                echo 'Updated';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=api%20(2).php">';
            }

        }
    }
```

with

```
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update']) && $_POST['chk']) {
        foreach($_POST['chk'] as $id){
            if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE api SET name='".$_POST['name'.$id]."', url='".$_POST['url'.$id]."', format='".$_POST['format'.$id]."'") == TRUE) {
                echo 'Updated';
            }
        }
        header('Location: api (2).php');
    }
```

and do same thing for delete

Comment: I want it to update every row if I press update, but I want it to just delete the selected ones. How would I do it for the update?

Comment: Mate, as I said, this won't even work. It won't get the post for some reason.

Comment: create phpfiddle and give me url

Comment: I don't know how to use it, do it yourself please. Updated the code a bit.
http://pastebin.com/FGwB4G5Q

Comment: And btw, the code you gave me was faulty in so many ways...
name='".$_POST['name'.$id]."'
Why the heck would you add the ID after the name? It's already being added on the other column, so the name is name1, name2.., with this it would become name11, name22..